# Rails asset pipeline, domain sharding, and caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline

I've got a question I can't seem to find a definitive answer to and I'm hoping someone can clear it up for me.

Using Rails 3.2 assets pipeline, and enabling domain sharding by setting `config.action_controller.asset_host` to something like `"http://foo%d.example.com"` will Rails always use the same host for each asset included in an HTML file or will it just choose a random one?

My concern here is that if the asset host is randomly chosen, users will have to redownload assets they may already have in their browser cache if they downloaded the asset from a different asset host previously.

Can anyone please shed some light on this? Or at least clear up any confusion I may have about the subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key [line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/asset_paths.rb#L118) is

```
(host =~ /%d/) ? host % (Zlib.crc32(source) % 4) : host
```

where source is the full path to the asset (i.e. something like '/assets/application-123456789012345678.css')

So any individual file will be consistently routed to the same host because the number is based on a checksum of the path.